# Clicking 'Unsubscribe' and 'Email Settings' links in "The Overflow Issue" email newsletter leads to 404 Page Not Found

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, email-notification, 404-not-found

Links to "Unsubscribe from emails like this" and "Edit email settings" in the "The Overflow Issue #3" email message that was recently sent out don't work. -- I tried to unsubscribe from the email but the link produces a 404 page not found.

Here is the url with personally identifying bits edited out:

> `https://itr-links.stackoverflow.email/e/eh?_t=XXX&_m=XXX&_e=XXX`

Comment: can you add the url you're trying to load without the personally identifying parameters?

Comment: The links look like this:

https://itr-links.stackoverflow.email/e/eh?_t=XXX&_m=XXX&_e=XXX
https://itr-links.stackoverflow.email/u/click?_t=XXX&_m=XXX&_e=XXX

Where 'XXX' is a bunch of letters/numbers/etc..

Comment: Going to the URLs w/o any query parameters = Bad Request For request 'GET /e/eh' [Missing parameter: _t]

Comment: One  does not simply unsubscribe from SE's newsletters.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the link, feel free to add more details about how to reproduce this issue :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking this now

Comment: Status-repro...

Answer (score 7):

I checked the email I received myself and the unsubscribe link worked just fine, we're also seeing traffic in our logs to indicate that the links are working.

Judging from the URL that you hit in our logs there's a double brace (`%7B%7B`) in there which really shouldn't be there. I've grabbed a copy of the email from our logs and the link appears to be formed correctly there and I can hit it successfully. If you try again it should be fine.

I'm going to speculate that a redirect went wrong here (possibly an issue with the third party that is used for these emails) and it failed to template the URL correctly.

Comment: Odd. The 'Edit Email Settings' link works now, however the 'unsubscribe' still 404's on me. Looking at the raw html src from the email the unsubscribe href url doesn't contain any %7B in it.

Comment: @NealAnders it is a redirect URL. I checked the redirect on the link you were sent and it correctly goes to the right place. I think you’re hitting a server from our email platform (a third party) that is doing something different to what I’m seeing. No way to tell without seeing the interaction between your browser and the server. If you can get that from your browser’s network tab we can isolate it further